# Which UUID to advertise a custom GATT server?

Tags: bluetooth, server, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm developing a custom GATT server: I mean a server which exposes non-standard services and characteristics.

What UUID I should use to advertise it?

From here:

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-attribute-profile

I guess I need to use the generic one: `0x1800`, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should use 128-bit random uuids for your non-standard services and characteristics. Short 16-bit uuids are only for services/characteristics defined by the Bluetooth standard.

EDIT: it's also possible to purchase 16-bit UUIDs from Bluetooth SIG.

Comment: It works but if I use a random 128-bit uuid to advertise my server I get from bluez backend for Qt5.7: "qt.bluetooth.bluez: services data does not fit into advertising data packet". This warning disappears if I use a pre-defined 16-bit uuid (i.e. heartrate).

Comment: The payload of 31-bytes must include also the name. Reducing its length the warning goes away.